# Undefined index: user_email.. read all other answers. still cant figure out

Tags: php, session

```
<?php
    include("includes/connections.php");

    if(isset($_POST['sign_in'])) {


        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);


        $get_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_password = '$password'";
        $run_user = mysqli_query($con,$get_user);

        $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

        if ($check==1) {

            $_SESSION['user_email']=$email;
            echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self');</script>";

        }
        else {

            echo "<script>alert('Password or email is not correct');</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self');</script>";

        }
    }

?>
```

Its been one day that i started learning php. I am stuck here. The code seems to be fine but it doesnt start the session on signup or login. It says **Undefined index: user_email**.

```
<h1>welcome : <?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?></h1>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: _Hint:_ You need to have a [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before using any sessions.

Comment: when i add the session_start() it gives me a notice saying session already started and ignoring it.

Comment: If you're just staring with PHP, don't start with the bad habit of concatenating your queries. You should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Put session_start() in the top of your page, before any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code at the point where 'check = 1', you need to put this line of code: session_start();

When you get an error the session is already started, you need to put this line of code at top of the document: ob_start();

```
<?php
 ob_start(); //Put ob_start(); here on this line


include("includes/connections.php");

        if(isset($_POST['sign_in'])) {


        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);


        $get_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_password = '$password'";
        $run_user = mysqli_query($con,$get_user);

        $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

        if ($check==1) {
            session_start(); //Put session_start(); on this line
            $_SESSION['user_email']=$email;
            echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self');</script>";

        }
        else {

            echo "<script>alert('Password or email is not correct');</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self');</script>";

        }
    }
```

?>

Comment: isn't it just easier to put `session_start()` in the top, before any output?

Comment: You are welcome! Had the same problem in the beginning when I started with sessions

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `session_start()` at the top of the page.

Comment: when i add the session_start() it gives me a notice saying session already started and ignoring it.

Comment: Put ob_start() above session_start();